# Check Mark/Tick Mark in XCUI Test

Tags: ios, uitableview, xctest, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I am currently automating iOS Native application using Appium 1.6.x

**Problem Statement:**
I am not able to find whether a TableCell is selected or not in Appium 1.6.x XCUITest framework. [A tick mark displays in the application on selecting, but not able to find that in automation]. The element attribute is as follows:

```
Device : iPad 10.x / Appium 1.6.1
Type: XCUIElementTypeCell
Accessibility Id:
Value:
Label:
Is Visible: true
Rect: x=694, y=195, h=44, w=320
Absolute XPath:
/AppiumAUT/XCUIElementTypeApplication/XCUIElementTypeWindow/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeOther[3]/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeTable/XCUIElementTypeCell
```

The same application when I inspect using Older appium 1.5.x UIAutomation framework, I am able to find the TableCell is selected or not. The element attribute is as follows:

```
Device : iPad 8.x / Appium 1.4.3
Name: Management
type: UIATableCell
value: 1
label:
enabled: true
visible: false
valid: true
location: {694, 195}
size: {320, 44}
xpath:     //UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAPopover[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[1]
```

Do anyone know the problem exists because of XCUI Test Framework or due to any other changes?

Comment: The XPATH which is used has to be modified for Appium 1.6.x.  Try with this //XCUIElementTypeTable/XCUIElementTypeCell